# Looping mysql query inside trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER update_status_penjualan AFTER UPDATE
    ON penjualan FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE arrayresult = (SELECT * FROM rincian_penjualan WHERE id_penjualan = OLD.id)     

  for ids in arrayresults

      UPDATE buku SET stok = stok + ids['jumlah']; WHERE noisbn = ids['noisbn'];                    

  endfor

END;

|

DELIMITER ;
```

I'v got many error, i think because my looping code is not right.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?
Thanks ~

Comment: What are the errors? We can't help if we don't know what the problem is. Please edit your question to add the detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a `cursor`, something like this:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER update_status_penjualan AFTER UPDATE
    ON penjualan FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

declare jumlah_c int;
declare noisbn_c int;
declare done int;
declare cur1 cursor for 
SELECT * FROM rincian_penjualan WHERE id_penjualan = OLD.id;
declare continue handler for not found set done=1;

    set done = 0;
    open cur1;
    igmLoop: loop   
    fetch cur1 into jumlah_c,noisbn_c;
     if done = 1 then leave igmLoop; end if;

      UPDATE buku SET stok = stok + jumlah_c WHERE noisbn = noisbn_c;                    

    end loop igmLoop;
    close cur1;

END;

|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: declare jumlah_c int;
declare noisbn_c int; is that automatically refers to colum jumlah and noisbn in buku table?

Comment: Yes, they correspond to each row of the select(`fetch cur1 into jumlah_c,noisbn_c`),I declare them as int, is that correct?